# Angular2/4 - dynamic forms - disable form controls when not visible

Tags: forms, angular, angular-reactive-forms

Is there a way to disable/enable form controls in an Angular4 app (using dynamic forms) as and when their visibility is flipped.

I could start calling disable()/enable() method on each and every form control in tandem with my ngIfs but just wondering if some one has a better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

u could use `[disabled]` on the control tag to disable the control which also exempt the form from the form validation.

Though u will get a warning when u try to use it directly on the tag. So i guess you best bet will be to use the `*ngIf`

Comment: I am using *ngIf to control the visibility. And as you said [disabled] does give a warning.